# How to fix terrain rendering in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a horror game and I have terrain that I paint a hole, but when I build it; the hole is filled, And I tried most of the ways but it was not fixed.

using Unity 2021.3.32f1

Please Help MEEEE
[The unity editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8XuJ.jpg)

[The built-in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ECcd.jpg)

There are any solutions that i can fix this problem

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "paint a hole"? or "the hole is filled"? You should probably include more info about what you have actually done, what the actual result is, and what result you are expecting.

Comment: how did you make the hole?

Comment: In unity terrain there are tool called Paint Hole that tool make hole in terrain.